# Getting error for : Application.Goto Workbooks("BOOK2.XLS").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4:F12")

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a run time error '9' script out of range when trying to run the code

```
Application.Goto Workbooks("BOOK2.XLS").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4:F12")
```

I am using Excel 2010.
I can see many users are able to use [this code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308) successfully, but why am I not getting it to work?
I am writing the code in book1 and trying to copy the data from book2:

```
Sub copy()
Application.Goto Workbooks("BOOK2.XLS").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4:F12")`
End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below by Siddarth, you are also not doing anything to copy data. Application.Goto selects the ranges specified, and will make the workbook/worksheet active if it's not already (assuming you pass in valid objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because of any one of the reasons

1. The Worksbook is actually not an .xls File. Check the extension.
2. The File is opened in another Excel Instance.
3. There is no workbook open by that name.

Comment: @ Leo : Thanks for the answer it worked, but i got to know that this workbook needs to be opened always while executing the code that will be a drawback.As i was looking for a solution to copy from any workbook and also we do not have to worry the file is opened or not and for that the address of the file should be mentioned as suggested by below but that code is also not doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Siddhath: Sorry i mistyped the name i was mentioning you in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a hyperlink:

```
Sub qwerty()
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="C:\TestFolder\ABC.xls"
    Sheets("xxx").Activate
    Range("H7").Select
End Sub
```

The advantage is that is does not matter if ABC.xls is open or not.

The hyperlink activity will open it if it is not already opened.

Comment: When i am copying data from book1.xls to book2.xlsx it's copying the book2.xlsx range in book2.xlsx only and not taking the reference of the book1.xls in the code. `Sub copy() ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="H:\Book1.xls" Sheets("Sheet1").Activate Range("A1").Select Selection.copy ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="H:\Book2.xlsx" Sheets("Sheet1").Activate Range("G1:G10").Select ActiveSheet.Paste End Sub`